# Lisp function exists or not checking

Tags: function, if-statement, autolisp

I want to check a function definition exists in a lisp program or not to decide which program block to run. 
The function definition is written on another file with.Net & I am working for AutoCAD. 
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but ultimately you need to check whether the symbol corresponding to the function name holds a value (for example using the `boundp` function), and perhaps additionally whether such value is of `SUBR`, `USUBR`, or `EXRXSUBR` data type (using the `type` function).

For example:

```
(member (type YourFunctionName) '(subr usubr exrxsubr))
```

In this case, if the symbol `YourFunctionName` is null, `(type YourFunctionName)` will return `nil` which will cause the `member` expression to return `nil`. Similarly, if the value held by the `YourFunctionName` symbol is anything other than a function, the `member` function will return `nil`.

Since any non-nil value in AutoLISP is interpreted as True, the use of `member` will validate an `if` test expression, even though `member` does not explicitly return a boolean value.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. It works. Actually, I am a newbie in lisp.

Answer (score 0):

Lee's Answer is great, many time to check function is loaded or not I am use `(and functionName)` it return `T` if exist or if not returns `Nil`.

Comment: Thank you Dinesh - just be aware that `(and functionName)` will return `T` if the symbol `functionName` holds *any* non-nil value, not only a function definition. This may or may not be likely depending on the obscurity of the function name used.